# I can't show data in UITableView

Tags: swift

I'm new to swift, I made a simple table and added 21 data in it.

When I debug, the compiler enters here, I see that there are 21.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(menus.count)
    return menus.count
}
```

but it doesn't go into this part

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeViewCell
    let men = menus[indexPath.row]
    print(men.Title)
    cell.mTitle.text = men.Title
    cell.subTitle.text =  men.SubTitle
    return cell
}
```

I'm learning new things from books, videos, sorry for the newbie question

I think I've done all the work but I couldn't figure out what I'm skipping I watched too many videos and I'm confused

all code,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    

    @IBOutlet weak var menuTable: UITableView!
    var menus = [Menu]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadMenus()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
        
    }
    
    func loadMenus(){
        for index in 0...20 {
            menus.insert(Menu(Image: "0", Title: "String \(index)", SubTitle: "String"), at: index)
        }
        self.menuTable.reloadData()
//        DispatchQueue.main.async {
//
//        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(menus.count)
        return menus.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeViewCell
        let men = menus[indexPath.row]
        print(men.Title)
        cell.mTitle.text = men.Title
        cell.subTitle.text =  men.SubTitle
        return cell
    }
}


class HomeViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var mTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var subTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mImage: UIImageView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you see ? Is the tableview empty or is the app crashing ?

Comment: i see blank lines

Comment: Did you assign the `class` of the cell in the storyboard to `HomeViewCell` ?

Comment: yes it is seen in the picture above mCell

Comment: https://ibb.co/6bzFWbQ

Comment: Could you give heightForRow the tableview? I think cell is correctly showing but there must be an issue in constraints in your cell

Comment: HeightForRow value is 138

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and everything works well.

The only thing I can think of:

Make sure you have assigned the class to the table view cell and connected the outlets.

What you showed me above is the identifier. See below for class.

[image: UITableViewCell Custom Class]

After I do this, I see the result:

[image: UITableView swift iOS]

Output in the console

```
21
21
21
String 0
String 1
String 2
String 3
String 4
String 5
String 6
String 7
String 8
String 9
String 10
String 11
String 12
String 13
String 14
```

Can you confirm you assigned `HomeViewCell` class to the Cell in storyboard ?

**Update**

You use auto layouts to set up your table and give the cell a height of 138 but you do not add any constraints for the subviews within your cell so I believe the runtime is unable to determine the actual height of your cell if the subviews in the cell do not have proper constraints.

add this UITableView delegate method and run your app to see if you see results:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 138
}
```

Of Course, change 138 to whatever you want or better yet configure your cell layout in autolayout.

End result:

[image: UITableViewCell height]

Comment: very strange, yes they are true, you can watch it on the video https://youtu.be/Z0TKn8TihTw

Comment: Your app seems to be crashing as I see in the console of your video. Is there anyway you can put this on repo, I can have a look and suggest a quick fix. I am sure it's something small.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FHKkeR7pR-I8hvYiIGo3qkYnq4ZvyTNY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @yhackup - please see my update.

Comment: oh that's why, I am enlightened, thank you very much, I thought it was enough to give height in the design. Thank you very much to you and my other friends who tried to help.

Comment: It is enough if also you set constraints for the subviews since you are using autolayouts. If this solved your problem, please consider accepting it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in viewDidLoad:

```
menuTable.register(HomeViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "mCell")
```

Comment: i got this error 
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: this is the pairing error as far as I know but the pairing seems correct https://ibb.co/098BMhg

Comment: Did you add the cell class name as HomeViewCell in stroyboard @yhackup

Comment: yes i added it i shared it above you can see it in this video https://youtu.be/Z0TKn8TihTw

Comment: You need to add height
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {} @yhackup

Comment: yes that is the cause of the problem. I thought it would be enough to just give it in the storyboard.